# function inside of IIFE not recognized

Tags: javascript, ajax, closures, iife

I have an IIFE that I am trying to make into a bookmarklet. I would like to have the modal the bookmarklet will pop up have some buttons that will call a function. However, when I have a structure like this:

```
(function(){

   var __myFn = function(str){ //also have tried function __myFn(){..}
      alert(str);
   }

   //some AJAX that builds HTML with the `result`s

   document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = "<span onclick='__myFn(" + result.someData+ ")'>test</span>


}());
```

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: __myFn is not defined`

How can I make this function recognized? Is there another way?

Comment: The `span` element is in the global scope, `__myFn()` is in the scope of the IIFE. You could use proper DOM manipulation methods and `addEventListener` to attach the event.

Comment: True, but I'm not sure how to do event delegation without a library which I think I would as these spans aren't on the page when it loads. I thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: Delegation? You can do it [on a newly-created element](http://jsfiddle.net/0pg61ba5/). You've to do this within a  callback function, if you're getting data from AJAX though.

Comment: @Teemu very nice. Thanks for that idea!

Answer (score 5):

When you use the `var` keyword, you're creating a variable that is local to the scope of the enclosing context. Since the enclosing context is a function, `__myFn` is local to the function itself and not known outside (i.e., not known in the global context).

If you want to use something that is inside, you would have to return a reference to it. You can use something like the module pattern for this:

```
var myModule = (function(){

   var __myFn = function(str) { 
      alert(str);
   }

   return {
       myFn: __myFn
   };

})();
```

Then you can do:

```
//some AJAX that builds HTML with the `result`s

document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = "<span onclick='myModule.myFn(" + result.someData+ ")'>test</span>
```

However, I recommend not binding your event handler this way. Use jQuery or use DOM methods ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) to bind event handlers. This way you could even do it inside the IIFE itself, which means you don't even have to return something from the IIFE. This means your global context is not polluted. Right now, the only reason you have to return something from the IIFE is because you are binding an event-handler inline via HTML.

Here are two examples. The first one assumes that the IIFE returns a reference to `__myFn`:

```
var resultDiv = document.getElementById("resultDiv");
resultDiv.addEventListener("click", myModule.myFn, false);
```

Here is the second example that does it within the IIFE itself:

```
(function(){

   var __myFn = function(str) { 
      alert(str);
   }

   var resultDiv = document.getElementById("resultDiv");
   resultDiv.addEventListener("click", __myFn, false);

})();
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the proper event binding, please?

Comment: @Bergi I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I have a few more questions. How could the events be bound if the element is loaded via ajax and is not on the page at the time the script is loaded? Also, in the first example, how could this be extended to support multiple functions. I tried `return {myFn: __myFn, myFn2: myFn2};` but it broke giving the error `undefined is not a function`

Answer (score -1):

For reasons I don't understand, I have found that taking the "var" off the declaration makes it work.

Example 1 (fails):

```
(function() {

    var counter = 0;
    var init = function() { console.log("init called"); }
})();

init(); // regardless of whether I named the function or not, this fails.
```

HOWEVER:
Example 2 (works):

```
(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    init = function() { console.log("init called"); }
})();

init(); // this calls the function just fine.
```

Note you can add any number of functions inside the iife this way just fine.

Comment: this is because without `var` you are creating/modifying `init` in global scope, that is why it's accessible later on. This isn't very good practice. Better to just return the closure, which is why Vivin Paliath's answer is preferable.