# Unexpected sequence of IIFE execution

Tags: javascript, iife

Am a bit of a self-taught JS hack and trying to be a little more formal as I have to build a better-behaved JS application that is name-spaced and a better JS citizen. I would appreciate some pointers on what I am doing wrong here.

The idea is to use the first closure to construct a namespace, then in the second I add a method a 'class' constructor to the namespace object. The I call a method on the sub.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    /**
     * @namespace ProjectX
     */

    var ProjectX = {

        attr1: 'I am inside ProjectX'
        
    }
    window.ProjectX = ProjectX;

})()

//console.log(ProjectX.attr1); // When this line is uncommented the code will output 'foobar' as expected?

(function() {
    'use strict';

    ProjectX.subObj = function(val) {
        this.name = val;
        return this;
    };
})();


var subObj = new ProjectX.subObj('Foobar');
console.log(subObj.name);
```

I am expecting to see 'Foobar' in the console log. However this yields the following result in the console:

> {
>     "message": "Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function",
>     "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
>     "lineno": 03,
>     "colno": 1
>   }

When I read this code I expect that the two IIFE's will execute in sequence, the first bringing ProjectX to life, then the second adding a further constructor to ProjectX that will return a subObj. Further, if the console.log((ProjectX.attr1) at line 16 is un-commented, the code will run as I anticipated. This seems to suggest that the ProjectX entity is not 'present' until I have referenced it. This contradicts my understanding of IIFE's, which is that they run immediately, and anyway, ProjectX is not a constructor - it is a global variable.

In researching I found [function inside of IIFE not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018435/function-inside-of-iife-not-recognized) which appears to be similar territory but is related to binding an event to the DOM and not a parallel to my query.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after first IIFE, which becomes relevant when the console.log with its semicolon is removed. You can search for the cases where semicolons are required in JS.  Also, you could try using es6 with babel to better organise your code and have better readability.

Comment: Thanks @sabithpocker. Re ES6 I have to cover current common browsers and I believe ES6 is not yet fully covered.

Comment: Try [Babel](https://babeljs.io)

Comment: If you're trying to update your skills, then move right to ES6 modules, which obviate the need for all this IIFE and roll-your-own-namespacing nonsense.

Comment: @torazaburo- straight question - what is the browser coverage for ES6 in your opinion? Looking at http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ it looks sketcjy on IE11 desktop and Android mobile - two of the largest usage clients.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Babel transpiles es6 code into es5 so there is no question on compatibility. You can write your code organised in es6 and deploy transpiled es5 version. Once browsers are all covered you can ship es6 as is and skip transpiling.

Comment: @sabithpocker - just been reading the history and current position of ES. I now understand your point on using Babel to transcompile ES 6 syntax to a compatible form of JS. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after first IIFE, which becomes relevant when the console.log with its semicolon is removed. You can search for the cases where semicolons are required in JS

Without semicolon, your code can be interpreted as:

```
(function() {
    var ProjectX = {
        attr1: 'I am inside ProjectX'
    }
    window.ProjectX = ProjectX;
})()(function() {
    ProjectX.subObj = function(val) {
        this.name = val;
        return this;
    };
})();
```

Check the following function in the format `(IIFE)()()`, this works because IIFE returns a function, which is invoked with `('Hey')`

```js
    (function() {
        return function(msg){console.log(msg)}
    })()('Hey')
```

Without semicolon, javascript expects that your first IIFE returns a function, which is not the case with your code so it throws a Type error saying that it is expecting a function but got undefined instead. Your code eventually evaluates to:

```
undefined(function() {
    ProjectX.subObj = function(val) {
        this.name = val;
        return this;
    };
})();
```

or more simplified as

```
undefined(<a function as parameter>)()
```

Which then throws the error that a `function` is expected here instead of `undefined`.

Read about higher order functions in javascript to get a better idea of this syntax and to what your code is being ambiguous against.

Comment: Just to confirm then, JS is seeing this as something like ()()()() which it resolves right to left? So the first IIFE has not been evaluated before the second is, at which point ProjectX is not defined. Correct ?

Comment: No, that's not right, it has nothing to do with ProjectX being defined. `myFunction()()()` is evaluated more like left to right rather than right to left. I'll try updating the answer to include more details.